# Assert.fail equivalent using hamcrest

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hamcrest

I use JUnit for `Assert.fail` but I do not know what is the Hamcrest equivalent. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MatcherAssert` class has this method:

```
public static void assertThat(String reason, boolean assertion) {
    if (!assertion) {
        throw new AssertionError(reason);
    }
}
```

So when invoked it would be the closest thing:

```
MatcherAssert.assertThat("Fail here", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your test is structured, I found this more natural using the not(anything()) Matchers.

```
@Test(expected = MyException.class)
public void runMyTestHere() {

    ...

    MyObj result = myService.getThing(id);
    assertThat("Exception should have been thrown.", result, is(not(anything())));
}
```